# How to make a class declared inside some namespace to be friend of other class defined in global scope

Tags: c++, c++17

I want class A::B to be the friend of C. There is another class with same name in namespace D.
How can I do this. In actual hierarchy, different classes may be in different headers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


class C
{
    friend class A::B;
};

namespace A
{
    class B
    {
    };
}

namespace D
{
    class B
    {
    };
}

int main()
{    
    cout << "Hello, friend!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the issue. Defining `C` after namespace `A` should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to forward declare class `B` (in the correct namespace) before `class C`:

```
namespace A {
    class B;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I was forward declaring incorrectly, like "class A::B"